# Use PyWinAuto and Python to monitor a script being run

Tags: python, powershell, pywinauto

What I want is for anytime a user tries to run a .Ps1 file, my Python script using PyWinAuto converts the file into an executable file and runs that.

This means I need:

- The fact that someone tried to run a .Ps1 (It will fail due to script-running permissions, so won't actually complete)
- The name and location of the file (So I can pass that into the Ps1ToExe converter)

Is there a way to have a Python script just acting as a Watcher, and then whenever this event occurs retrieve the neccessary information?

I can do all the actual conversion, just getting the information in the first place I'm struggling with.

Thanks.

Comment: Pywinauto is for GUI only. It looks like you need some file execution hook. Because .ps1 script can run from cmd.exe or powershell or by double click on the file in explorer.exe. I think technically it should be possible. Do you need to catch all these ways to execute the file?

Comment: The only execution I need to monitor is through PowerShell. Because the script won't run, I basically want any time the user tries to to automatically convert it so it *will* run.

Comment: Would it be easier to monitor whenever a file is saved as a .Ps1 and convert it then, before it's even run?